# jQuery get final total using sum of all values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking to append multiple values from input boxes to one another, actually... I don't just need to append them, I actually want to SUM their values as they are dollar amounts.

Normally I could do this but I have the input boxes showing up using an incrementation for the IDs (user clicks a button, input field appears, dollar amount is entered, **THEN that value is added/summed to the final total**)

```
   $("input[id^=sum_" + i).sum("keyup", "#totalSum_" + i);
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoleScotsburn/kzreojc6/5/

I want the "final total" to show up using all the values under the "total" column

Comment: It looks like you tried to include a local script with some custom plugin in the fiddle, and that won't work.

Comment: You have a document ready inside a document ready. And it is being fired onload.

Comment: And everything has the same id, ids are singular.

Comment: Removed the additional document ready, as for the IDs the calculation sum function adds together all input fields with matching ids, thats why it's like that

Answer (score 0):

you can make benefit of event propagation
lets assume that u add all the input text element in div with id = container

```
$('#container').change(function(e){
var sum = 0;
$(this).find('.toSum').each(function(index,el){
    var val = $(el).val();
    if(val && val != "")
        sum+= parseInt(val);
});
$('#totalSum').val(sum);
});
```

the div catch the change event of any element within it, then you handle it to re-sum all the elements

check this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/mfarouk/qy39ptkq/2/

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
var total = 0;
$("input[id^=sum_" + i).each(function() {
  total += $(this).value();
});
```

Comment: This some what works for me, when I add it, it does a final total on the first new row added by clicking the button and does not add to the finaltotal input field and disables all the other total input boxes.